# Regex match up to the end of a standard pattern

Tags: c#, regex, search

I'm working on an application to manage filenames of downloaded TV Shows. Basically it will search the directory and clean up the filenames, removing things like full stops and replacing them with spaces and getting rid of the descriptions at the end of the filename after the easily recognizable pattern of, for eg., S01E13. (.1080p.BluRay.x264-ROVERS)

What I want to do is to make a regex expression for use in C# to just extract whatever is before the SnnEnn including itself (where n is any whole positive integer).
But, i don't know much regex to get me going

For example, if I had the filename TV.Show.S01E01.1080p.BluRay.x264-ROVERS, the query would only get TV.Show.S01E01, irrespective of how many words are before the pattern, so it could be TV.Show.On.ABC.S01E01 and it would still work.

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: So learn how to do it... Try it when you fail after trying ask the question with  a code in it. And we will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
string input = "TV.Show.S01E01.1080p.BluRay.x264-ROVERS";
            string pattern = @"(?'pattern'^.*\d\d[A-Z]\d\d)";
            string results = Regex.Match(input, pattern).Groups["pattern"].Value;
```

Comment: try this out `(?'pattern'.*S\d\dE\d\d)`

Answer (score 0):

There is more obvious way without regex:

```
string GetNameByPattern(string s)
{
    const string pattern_length = 6; //SnnEnn

    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length - pattern_length; i++)
    {
        string part = s.SubString(i, pattern_length);

        if (part[0] == 'S' && part[3] == 'N') //candidat
            if (Char.IsDigit(part[1]) && Char.IsDigit(part[2]) && Char.IsDigit(part[4]) && Char.IsDigit(part[5])) 
                return s.SubString(0, i + pattern_length);
    }

    return "";
}
```